# can I add a custom format to the format option in the text panel?

Tags: formatting, text

In the text editor, where you can set headings and other settings, is it possible to add your own styles for clients to use? and even remove the unnecessary ones?

Comment: WP3 and TinyMCE is so messed up in this aspect. I cannot believe that it's not possible to easily add or customize the damn formats like it is in CKEditor.

Comment: I agree, it's a total pain.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The "classic" TinyMCE editor has two dropdowns: `formatselect` for *paragraph styles* and `styleselect` for *character styles* - which can also contain paragraph styles, to make it more confusing. The configuration in WordPress by default only shows the *format* dropdown. If you apply a custom stylesheet to the editor, TinyMCE can use it to pick up the classnames and add them to the *style* dropdown - but this did not work every time for me.

Since 3.0 you can call [`add_editor_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style) in your `functions.php` to add a stylesheet to the editor. By default it's `editor-style.css` in your theme directory. Before 3.0 you have to hook into the `mce_css` filter to add the URL to your editor stylesheet. This will end up in [the `content_css` TinyMCE configuration value](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aConfiguration/content_css).

To add the *style* dropdown, the `styleselect` option must appear in one of the button bar configuration arrays ([`theme_advanced_buttons[1-4]`](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aConfiguration/theme_advanced_buttons_1_n) in TinyMCE, filtered by `mce_buttons_[1-4]` in WordPress). The list of block formats is controlled by [the `theme_advanced_blockformats` option of TinyMCE](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aConfiguration/theme_advanced_blockformats), which you can add to the control array in the [`tiny_mce_before_init`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/tiny_mce_before_init) filter. If you want to customize the names of the *style* dropdown (not just your CSS class names), look at [the `theme_advanced_styles` option](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aConfiguration/theme_advanced_styles). You can also use the more advanced [`style_formats` option](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aConfiguration/style_formats) which gives you more flexibility to define the styles.

The relevant PHP code with all the hooks and default configuration is in [`wp-admin/includes/post.php`, in function `wp_tiny_mce()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/includes/post.php#L1446). All together, your setup could look like this:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse3882_after_setup_theme' );
function wpse3882_after_setup_theme()
{
    add_editor_style();
}

add_filter('mce_buttons_2', 'wpse3882_mce_buttons_2');
function wpse3882_mce_buttons_2($buttons)
{
    array_unshift($buttons, 'styleselect');
    return $buttons;
}

add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'wpse3882_tiny_mce_before_init');
function wpse3882_tiny_mce_before_init($settings)
{
    $settings['theme_advanced_blockformats'] = 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4';

    // From http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/example_24.php
    $style_formats = array(
        array('title' => 'Bold text', 'inline' => 'b'),
        array('title' => 'Red text', 'inline' => 'span', 'styles' => array('color' => '#ff0000')),
        array('title' => 'Red header', 'block' => 'h1', 'styles' => array('color' => '#ff0000')),
        array('title' => 'Example 1', 'inline' => 'span', 'classes' => 'example1'),
        array('title' => 'Example 2', 'inline' => 'span', 'classes' => 'example2'),
        array('title' => 'Table styles'),
        array('title' => 'Table row 1', 'selector' => 'tr', 'classes' => 'tablerow1'),
    );
    // Before 3.1 you needed a special trick to send this array to the configuration.
    // See this post history for previous versions.
    $settings['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );

    return $settings;
}
```

Comment: is there a special format the .css should take using add_editor_style? nothing seems to happen

Comment: Still no joy in working out how to add classes to the format pulldown other than the default.

Comment: @Mild Fuzz: My earlier answer was misleading because WordPress shows only one of the two needed dropdowns. I updated my answer with a way to add the second dropdown and how to control it.

Comment: you leg end!! not sure what the 'style_formats' is doing, but the 'theme_advanced_styles' does exactly what I need!!

Comment: really trying to get that second block taking an effect, as it seems like it would be immensely useful. Trouble is $settings['style_formats'] is null before we set it, so I can't compare formats with anything.

Comment: @Mild Fuzz: The parameters to the different `style_formats` items are explained in the related [`formats`](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/formats) wiki page.

Comment: that shows it all in JS, bit confused about how to convert that to PHP that works. Tried '$settings['style_formats'] .= "custom_format : {block : 'h1', attributes : {title : \"Header\"}, styles : {color : red}}";' but it kills tinyMCE completely

Comment: @Mild Fuzz: I thought WordPress would apply `json_encode()` to the config, but it just prints it out. I modified my answer to include some "JS-injection" to pass an array config to TinyMCE. Not guaranteed to work.

Comment: no longr produces errors, but has no effect!

Comment: Does the sample code work and did it solve your question? Note that you have a typo at the end of line "Table styles", it needs a ) and not a }

Comment: json_encode generates " and not ' so the javascript breaks. You need to do str_replace('"', "'", json_encode($style_formats))

Comment: How do you rename the dropdown button from Formats?

Comment: @raison: Best to ask that in a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

You can add custom format or remove exist in that way:

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', function($init_array) {
    $init_array['formats'] = json_encode([
        // add new format to formats
        'h3marked' => [
            'selector' => 'h3',
            'block'    => 'h3',
            'classes'  => 'article-paragraph',
        ],
    ], JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);

    // remove from that array not needed formats
    $block_formats = [
        'Paragraph=p',
        'Heading 1=h1',
        'Heading 2=h2',
        'Heading 3=h3',
        'Heading 3 marked=h3marked',    // use the new format in select
        'Heading 4=h4',
        'Heading 5=h5',
        'Heading 6=h6',
        'Preformatted=pre',
    ];
    $init_array['block_formats'] = implode(';', $block_formats);

    return $init_array;
});
```

See more in [this post](https://stevegrunwell.com/blog/wordpress-tinymce-block-formats/) and this [tinymce docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/configure/content-formatting/)

Answer (score 0):

As per here [TinyMCE format dropdown no longer showing style previews](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112210/tinymce-format-dropdown-no-longer-showing-style-previews/116790#116790)

Kara had it right, you need to unset the default styles to see the new styles...

```
unset($init['preview_styles']);

return $settings;
```

Comment: Please add some more detail, it's e.g. not clear what `$settings` is here. Thanks