# TinyMCE: adding CSS to format dropdown

Tags: css, tinymce

I successfully added a TinyMCE stylesheet using add_editor_style() so that I can preview the styles in the body of the TinyMCE editor.

However, am I right in assuming that the add_editor_style() function can only access style for the body of the editor?

If so, is there another method or function that I can use to access the styling of the TinyMCE Format dropdown as well?

[image]

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can not enhance the drop-down list `formatselect`. But you can enhance with the hook `tiny_mce_before_init` the second drop down `styleselect`, there is to hide in a default WordPress install.
The [documentation](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:formats) list all defaults and possibilities.

- inline – Name of the inline element to produce, for example “span”. The current text selection will be wrapped in this inline element.
- block – Name of the block element to produce, for example "h1". Existing block elements within the selection gets replaced with the new block element.
- selector – CSS 3 selector pattern to find elements within the selection by. This can be used to apply classes to specific elements or complex things like odd rows in a table.
- classes – Space separated list of classes to apply to the selected elements or the new inline/block element.
- styles – Name/value object with CSS Style items to apply such as color etc.
- attributes – Name/value object with attributes to apply to the selected elements or the new inline/block element.
- exact – Disables the merge similar styles
  feature when used. This is needed for some CSS inheritance issues
  such as text-decoration for underline/strike though.
- wrapper – State that tells that the current format is a container format for block
  elements. For example, a div wrapper or blockquote.

### The Style Button

Note that, by default, the Style dropdown is hidden on WordPress. At first add the button for custom formats to a menu bar of TinyMCE, in example line 2 with hook `mce_buttons_2`.

```
add_filter( 'mce_buttons_2', 'fb_mce_editor_buttons' );
function fb_mce_editor_buttons( $buttons ) {
    
    array_unshift( $buttons, 'styleselect' );
    return $buttons;
}
```

### The Custom Styles

Then enhance the drop-down of this button. Also useful the enhancement via additional value in the array, see the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/tiny_mce_before_init) for this example.

```
/**
 * Add styles/classes to the "Styles" drop-down
 */ 
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'fb_mce_before_init' );

function fb_mce_before_init( $settings ) {

    // Set to true to include the default settings.
    $settings['style_formats_merge'] = true;
    
    $style_formats = array(
        array(
            'title' => 'Download Link',
            'selector' => 'a',
            'classes' => 'download'
            ),
        array(
            'title' => 'My Test',
            'selector' => 'p',
            'classes' => 'mytest',
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'AlertBox',
            'block' => 'div',
            'classes' => 'alert_box',
            'wrapper' => true
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Red Uppercase Text',
            'inline' => 'span',
            'styles' => array(
                'color'         => 'red', // or hex value #ff0000
                'fontWeight'    => 'bold',
                'textTransform' => 'uppercase'
            )
        )
    );
    
    $settings['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );
    
    return $settings;

}
```

### Result

[image]

### Enhanced Drop down menu

You can also enhance the drop-down with a tree menu. Create the var from the example source above with more structure in the array, like the follow source.

```
    $style_formats = array(
        array(
            'title' => 'Headers',
                'items' => array(
                array(
                    'title' => 'Header 1',
                    'format' => 'h1',
                    'icon' => 'bold'
                ),
                array(
                    'title' => 'Header 2',
                    'format' => 'h2',
                    'icon' => 'bold'
                )
            )
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Download Link',
            'selector' => 'a',
            'classes' => 'download'
        )
    );
```

[image]

For more possibilities and parameters, see the default values of the Style Format drop-down field (writing in JavaScript).

```
var defaultStyleFormats = [
    {title: 'Headers', items: [
        {title: 'Header 1', format: 'h1'},
        {title: 'Header 2', format: 'h2'},
        {title: 'Header 3', format: 'h3'},
        {title: 'Header 4', format: 'h4'},
        {title: 'Header 5', format: 'h5'},
        {title: 'Header 6', format: 'h6'}
    ]},

    {title: 'Inline', items: [
        {title: 'Bold', icon: 'bold', format: 'bold'},
        {title: 'Italic', icon: 'italic', format: 'italic'},
        {title: 'Underline', icon: 'underline', format: 'underline'},
        {title: 'Strikethrough', icon: 'strikethrough', format: 'strikethrough'},
        {title: 'Superscript', icon: 'superscript', format: 'superscript'},
        {title: 'Subscript', icon: 'subscript', format: 'subscript'},
        {title: 'Code', icon: 'code', format: 'code'}
    ]},

    {title: 'Blocks', items: [
        {title: 'Paragraph', format: 'p'},
        {title: 'Blockquote', format: 'blockquote'},
        {title: 'Div', format: 'div'},
        {title: 'Pre', format: 'pre'}
    ]},

    {title: 'Alignment', items: [
        {title: 'Left', icon: 'alignleft', format: 'alignleft'},
        {title: 'Center', icon: 'aligncenter', format: 'aligncenter'},
        {title: 'Right', icon: 'alignright', format: 'alignright'},
        {title: 'Justify', icon: 'alignjustify', format: 'alignjustify'}
    ]}
];
```

### Add Custom Stylesheet to the editor

Now is the last point, that you include the custom css for this formats, via hook `mce_css`.

```
/**
 * Apply styles to the visual editor
 */  
add_filter( 'mce_css', 'fb_mcekit_editor_style');
function fb_mcekit_editor_style($url) {

    if ( ! empty( $url ) )
        $url .= ',';

    // Retrieves the plugin directory URL
    // Change the path here if using different directories
    $url .= trailingslashit( plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) ) . '/my-editor-styles.css';

    return $url;
}
```

Don't forget to add this stylesheet rules also to the front end stylesheet.

### Remove the Format Button

As enhancement you can remove the `formatselect` drop down button via check for the value in the button array. Add the follow source to the function `fb_mce_editor_buttons` at the hook `mce_buttons_2`.

```
$value = array_search( 'formatselect', $buttons );
if ( FALSE !== $value ) {
    foreach ( $buttons as $key => $value ) {
        if ( 'formatselect' === $value )
            unset( $buttons[$key] );
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I understand this conceptually: essentially you remove WP's standard Formatting box, and then add your own Style dropdown in order to control the styling. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Right. Currently I can't find a hook to change the `formatselect`Dropdown. This Dropdown have not a function to build a menu, is static values in the tinymce.js of WP.

Comment: Also the hint to this [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3882/can-i-add-a-custom-format-to-the-format-option-in-the-text-panel), there I have found now.

Comment: Ah ok! Thanks, this is a good solution for now. I'll try it out!

Comment: It still seems that the stylesheet only applies to the content in the editor. And that styling the elements in the dropdown is done via the `'styles'` setting of the settings array. Is this correct? Even though the [tinyMCE example](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/custom_formats.php) seems to indicate otherwise.

Comment: Note: The default styles can be added to the formats dropdown by adding `$settings['style_formats_merge'] = true;` into »fb_mce_before_init()«.

Comment: @bueltge, is it possible to attach a google fonts link to the $url value before our custom stylesheet is attached?  How would that look like in your example above within "add custom stylesheet to editor"?

Comment: You can define custom fonts, yes. I answered this question for a while in [another question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240098/append-font-family-in-tinymce/240791#240791). That's should helps you.

Comment: I cannot get "color" under "styles" array to work. If I do like this `'styles' => [ 'color'         => 'red', 'textTransform' => 'uppercase' ]` only text-transform is applied to inline-style. Not color. Even with HEX values.

Answer (score 5):

Per [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/116790/6477), the key to getting the styles to appear in the dropdown is to `unset($settings['preview_styles']);`

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'fb_mce_before_init' );
function fb_mce_before_init( $settings ) {

    // customize as desired

    // unset the preview styles
    unset($settings['preview_styles']);`

    return $settings;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Very helpful and thanks for `defaultstyles` pointers.  I found merging arrays wasn't working until converting those default options to valid JSON (not valid JavaScript).  Below allows **appending** the WordPress tinymce's drop-down instead of **replacing**

Default options (JSON):

```
$defaults = '[{ "title": "Headers", "items": [
        { "title": "Header 1", "format": "h1" },
        { "title": "Header 2", "format": "h2" },
        { "title": "Header 3", "format": "h3" },
        { "title": "Header 4", "format": "h4" },
        { "title": "Header 5", "format": "h5" },
        { "title": "Header 6", "format": "h6" }
    ] },

    { "title": "Inline", "items": [
        { "title": "Bold", "icon": "bold", "format": "bold" },
        { "title": "Italic", "icon": "italic", "format": "italic" },
        { "title": "Underline", "icon": "underline", "format": "underline" },
        { "title": "Strikethrough", "icon": "strikethrough", "format": "strikethrough" },
        { "title": "Superscript", "icon": "superscript", "format": "superscript" },
        { "title": "Subscript", "icon": "subscript", "format": "subscript" },
        { "title": "Code", "icon": "code", "format": "code" }
    ] },

    { "title": "Blocks", "items": [
        { "title": "Paragraph", "format": "p" },
        { "title": "Blockquote", "format": "blockquote" },
        { "title": "Div", "format": "div" },
        { "title": "Pre", "format": "pre" }
    ] },

    { "title": "Alignment", "items": [
        { "title": "Left", "icon": "alignleft", "format": "alignleft" },
        { "title": "Center", "icon": "aligncenter", "format": "aligncenter" },
        { "title": "Right", "icon": "alignright", "format": "alignright" },
        { "title": "Justify", "icon": "alignjustify", "format": "alignjustify" }
        ] }
 ]';
```

In functions.php return the larger options hash:

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'fb_mce_before_init' );
function fb_mce_before_init( $settings ) {

    $style_formats = array(
    //....

    $settings['style_formats'] = json_encode( array_merge( json_decode($defaults), $style_formats ) );
    return $settings;
}
```

Comment: Note: The default styles can be added to the formats dropdown by adding `$settings['style_formats_merge'] = true;` into »fb_mce_before_init()«.