# How to style text in Wordpress

Tags: css, visual-editor, text

I have recently moved to using Wordpress from Joomla and everything has been good apart from one niggling issue.

When I go to edit text, I can't select much in the way of styling, only the actual heading types, bold italic etc. This is obviously because it is set to use the CSS themes and nothing else. It would be nice to change the colour of whatever parts I want for example.

I also have the same problem with tables. In my theme it is set to a light grey background and nothing else, so all I can do is add text to my table cells but absolutely nothing else. I would like to be able to give each column a different colour because the tables hold details about packages which come in bronze, silver and gold.

Is there a way to overcome this? I added CKEditor but it didn't provide a solution to these problems.

Comment: There is a similar question and answer to this here: 

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128931/tinymce-adding-css-to-format-dropdown

Comment: @BrandtSolovij I'm pretty sure that's nothing to do with what I'm asking. It looks to me like that OP is asking about styling the dropdowns within TinyMCE. I wouldn't however be surprised if the question has been asked, I just can't find it.

Comment: Actually the above reference is relevant, as you are looking to override the theme you are using and provide custom CSS styling to elements of your choosing, from within the WYSIWYG.

Comment: if you are trying to "style" anything from the tinyMCE wysiwyg, the proper way is to extend the tinyMCE's style library. It is up to you (or your developer) to specify the proper css, but the accepted way to is to plug/filter in this manner. This is at least how I understand the wordpress ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of WordPress, there a text color option in the default [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG), which is TinyMCE.

Look for this option:

[image: The text color option in TinyMCE]

Custom styling for tables is not supported by default in WordPress.