# content editor format style tags

Tags: functions

This is the code I'm using to generate format styles for content editor:

```
// Callback function to filter the MCE settings
function my_mce_before_init_insert_formats( $init_array ) {  
    // Define the style_formats array
    $style_formats = array(  
        // Each array child is a format with it's own settings
        array(  
            'title' => 'lato-reg-16-gray',  
            'selector' => 'p',  
            'classes' => 'lato-reg-16-gray',
            'wrapper' => true,
      'styles' => array(
        'font-family' => 'Lato',
        'font-weight' => 'normal',
        'font-size' => '16px',
        'line-height' => '19px',
        'color' => '#7d7c7c',
      )
        ),
    );  
    // Insert the array, JSON ENCODED, into 'style_formats'
    $init_array['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );  
    return $init_array;  
} 
// Attach callback to 'tiny_mce_before_init' 
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_mce_before_init_insert_formats' );
```

It works for text that is not formatted but if I try to apply the `lato-reg-16-gray` to a list element `li` the option is grayed and it doesn't let me use it. How can I apply the style to this type of elements?

I don't want to create a specific style to the `li` since I'll be creating more format styles for the user so he can choose any style to use on a `li` or any other elements. For example `ol`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your source you allow only the selector tag `p` for the class - `'selector' => 'p',`.

You find a longer answer with examples in this [WPSE-Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128931/tinymce-adding-css-to-format-dropdown/128950). I think is not helpful to share the same content here in this question.