# How to use a TinyMCE filter?

Tags: filters, tinymce

I am new in WordPress. I am trying to add a filter for tinymce like:

```
function wpdocs_teeny_mce_button( $buttons, $editor_id ) {
    $buttons = array('bold', 'italic');
    return $buttons;
}
add_filter( 'teeny_mce_buttons', 'wpdocs_teeny_mce_button', 10, 2 );
```

But I am not getting any change in my editor. Please help

Comment: What is the goal? You will remove default buttons and leave only bold and italic as button? You use the wrong hook, WP use 3 different hooks for each line in the TinyMCE, like `mce_buttons`, `mce_buttons_2`. See also [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128931/tinymce-adding-css-to-format-dropdown/128950#128950) for more background and hints.

Comment: I want to add only 2 button and want to remove rest all from editor.