# How to manage heading font options located in the wysiwyg editor for posts and pages

Tags: wysiwyg

Within WordPress 4.6.1, when I go to edit a post, from the WYSIWYG editor, there is a drop-down option to apply multiple heading formats to the given text.

[image]

What is the WordPress way for developers to customize these heading options so that we can adjust the font size, color and font-family, for any one of these dropdown options?
also can we add more options to the drop down?

Comment: I think this answer could help you: [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128931/tinymce-adding-css-to-format-dropdown](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128931/tinymce-adding-css-to-format-dropdown)

Comment: Thanks! That's was 2 years ago.  Has anything changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128931/tinymce-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Badding-css-to-format%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B-dropdown).

Now my little answer to your question in the comments: I can't guarantee that anything has changed since then. But I think it is a good base to start to do what you want to. And I can't remember big changes with tinyMCE in the last time.

Comment: Thanks again.  I'm gonna try out some of these past solutions tomorrow to confirm.

Comment: The process works like a charm in WordPress 4.6.1  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and good to hear that everything is working. :)